# UwAmp restart crashes Chrome pages

Tags: uwamp

Whenever UwAmp restarts itself (for example, when I modify php.ini or switch to a different version of php) it often crashes whatever Chrome pages I have opened, whether they are pages that I'm testing on UwAmp or something completely unrelated like Facebook. They go blank and I have to reload them. Sometimes it closes Chrome altogether, I have to restart it and I get the message saying that Chrome closed unexpectedly. What gives? Is this a known bug? Is there any way to prevent it? How and why does UwAmp even have control over Chrome? This is on Windows 10 x64, UwAmp 3.1.0, latest 64-bit Chrome.

Thanks!

EDIT: It just closed Notepad++ on me, so it's not specific to Chrome. There's also a message that pops up sometimes within UwAmp, saying that the process couldn't be killed because access was denied. Maybe UwAmp is trying to kill the wrong process? It also happens when I manually click the "Stop" button.

Comment: It happens to me to, but only when I start Apache without starting MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

That's an issue I encounter too. If I exit UwAmp, sometimes it force closes another program (Firefox, qBittorrent, Spotify...)

I had reported this issue to the developer, but got no reply.

So, I guess we'll have to live with it.

Comment: Happens to me too. Kills random program.

Answer (score 1):

When you start your session/computer, open first all the other softwares you wish to use (chrome, firefox, aBittorrent, Sportify or whatsoever). Then at the **end**, open uwamp.

It shouldn't crash down other softwares when you stop/start apache/mysql, or when you close down uwamp.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but that's really not very practical. In any case, UwAmp has been abandoned by its developer, so I'll have to move on, sooner or later. A shame, because I like it. I'll switch to XAMPP or something.

Comment: It works, but I'm that guy who closes his browser and IDE at midday to go eating.
So I have to close and restart uwampp.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to open `uwamp.ini` and change the `AUTO_RESTAT_CONFIG_CHANGED` to `"0"`.

This will disable uWamp's auto-restart feature during server configuration changes.

Comment: Yes, that can be changed within the preferences even, no need to edit the ini file. The problem is that the server usually needs to be restarted if configuration changes are made, which can happen often during development.

Regardless, UwAmp has long been abandoned, so I switched to XAMPP and I suggest that anyone still using UwAmp also switches to something else.